# Why does dplyr filter_all using all_vars > 0 work on a character string?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Given:

```
df <- structure(list(word = c("aaliyahmaxwell", "abasc", "abbslovesfed", 
"abbycastro", "abc", "abccarpet", "abdul", "ability", "abnormile", 
"abraham"), chardonnay = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), coffee = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("word", "chardonnay", 
"coffee"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Why does `df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. > 0))` work?

I mean that my first column is of type character and can't be > 0.
I can understand why it works on the other two columns but need an explanation on why it works when I have a mixture of character and double type columns.

Please advise.

Comment: I think the 0 gets type changed to character "0" and then the comparison would be "a" > "0"

Comment: @akrun but here the goal is to select columns that both have numbers > 0.
Please explain.

Comment: @akrun but why "a" > "0"?

Comment: Are you looking for `df %>% filter_if(is.numeric, ~ . > 0)`? This looks to the numeric columns and only keeps the rows where all values >0, which is no rows in this case. This sidesteps concerns about how the character column is tested.

Comment: @JonSpring thanks a lot for an alternative!!
Please post as additional answer.

Also what is OP? Original Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to type change.  Here, `0` a numeric entry gets type converted to a character one.  According to `?Comparison

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

```
df %>%
   filter(word > 0)
```

giving all the rows of the original data because

```
letters > 0
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#[26] TRUE
```

In the 'word' column, it is all characters which would any way be greater than "0" due to type conversion, leaving only the `all_vars` to essentially check whether the other numeric columns are greater than 0

---

In the OP's dataset example, none of the rows match the criteria because one of the numeric columns is always less than or equal to 0 in each of the rows.  If we change the first row of 'coffee' to 2 or 1, that row would be picked up because the 'chardonnay' is greater than 0, the first column 'word' is always greater

```
df$coffee[1] <- 2
df %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(. > 0))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  word           chardonnay coffee
#   <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 aaliyahmaxwell          4      2
```

---

To select only numeric columns, use `filter_if` (as in the comments)

```
df %>% 
   filter_if(is.numeric, all_vars(. > 0))
```

Comment: You mean that if one my words = "" it will filter it out? @akrun

Comment: @SteveS It is due to the type conversion and now the comparison iss between character elements

Comment: Thanks dear akrun!
Please explain why "a" > "0"

Comment: Is it because characters are always > numbers according your quote:

If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

Comment: @SteveS  Yes, that is true

Comment: Thank you so much dear akrun! I learn so much from your great knowledge!
You are a real GURU and TEACHER! Thanks for sharing your knowledge!!!

Comment: @SteveS  Good to know that my inputs were useful for you.  I would say the knowlege works in both ways.  It is because of questions and answers from  you guys, I learn a lot.  Regarding title/adjectives, I would prefer without any

Comment: @DSGym It also depends on the behaior of as.numeric.  Also, in the precedence, it is below of character

Answer (score 2):

Even though there is already a good answer, I think this can be made clearer with an example:

```
> c("a", 0)
[1] "a" "0"
```

Here you can see what happens, the number gets coerced to a character.

Characters get compared lexically. Example:

```
> "b" > "a" 
[1] TRUE

> "a" > "5"
[1] TRUE

> charvector <- sample(c(seq(1,9), LETTERS))
> charvector
 [1] "6" "D" "T" "U" "I" "R" "F" "S" "J" "W" "B" "A" "8" "E" "2" "7" "O" "Z" "V" "G" "9" "4" "H" "C" "Y" "1" "X" "5" "M" "K" "Q" "L" "N" "3" "P"
```

The order becomes also clear when you sort that vector:

```
> sort(charvector)
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```